# JObject.Parse retornando nulo

Tags: c#, json, youtube-api, yaml

Não estou muito adaptado ao Youtube Api V3. Mas eu assisti uma live da google developers onde o operador da google mostra como listar a atividade de um determinado canal. Com base nisso eu executei via `GET` pelo seguinte endereço:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&channelId=UCaNLpnBnxEeQGfEym8bUr-g&maxResults=1&key={SUA_KEY_DE_DESENVOLVIMENTO}`

e ele me retornou esse código. Mas esse código não estou conseguindo fazer Parse em json nele, pois ele começa com `{ ... }` e não o padrão que no caso seria `nome_do_obj:{ ... }`, mas sendo que `{ ... }` não tem inicio da definição do objeto. Utilizei o código:

OBS: Utilizei o https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

para decifrar o código:

```
using using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public string TentarDecifrar(string textoJson, string key, string value){
JObject jsonData = new JObject(JObject.Parse(textoJson));

return jsonData[key][value];
}
```

Mas como o primeio objeto não tem nome/identificação ele retorna `NullOperationException` quando eu executo

```
void Main(){ MessageBox.Show(TentarDecifrar(CONTEUDO_EM_JSON_QUE_O_YOUTUBE_DATA_API_ME_RETORNA, "items", "description"));}
```

No caso quando eu consultasse o JObject seria

```
jsonData[""]["items"]["description"] 
/* no caso onde está [""] é onde aparece o objeto que não possui identificação ,ou seja:
{           <= nesta linha
"kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
 "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/HzaV00F-8u901Ma6Odl2HflceQE\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA", ... }
*/
```

Eu quero pegar a key `items` e o valor por exemplo `description`, onde a variável `CONTEUDO_EM_JSON_QUE_O_YOUTUBE_DATA_API_ME_RETORNA` é igual a:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
 "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/HzaV00F-8u901Ma6Odl2HflceQE\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 6,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#activity",
   "etag": "\"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/yikeFjK_8QolzIG4MyBtbexRdjs\"",
   "id": "VTE0NDU3ODg1NTYxMzk4MjAyMjI2NDc2OTY=",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-10-25T15:55:56.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCaNLpnBnxEeQGfEym8bUr-g",
    "title": "Minecraft - MiniGames # 1",
    "description": "Todo canal de gamer tem que ter minecraft né ? haha\n\nPag:  www.facebook.com/franporfirio98",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6AzmgmtHTGY/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6AzmgmtHTGY/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6AzmgmtHTGY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6AzmgmtHTGY/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6AzmgmtHTGY/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Fran Gamer",
    "type": "upload"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

> **Resumindo...**
>   Eu queria desenvolver um aplicativo em WinForms para com que eu consulte o youtube api v3 e ele retorne em json com os dados do ultimo vídeo enviado daquele determinado canal. Mesmo disso ainda tenho duvidadas entre Json e Yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
var jsonData = JObject.Parse(textoJson);

var items = (JArray)jsonData["items"];
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var snippet = item["snippet"];
    var description = (JValue)snippet["description"];
    Console.WriteLine(description.Value);
}
```

Edit:
Pra filtrar pelo type do snippet:
var jsonData = JObject.Parse(json);

```
var items = (JArray)jsonData["items"];

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var snippet = item["snippet"];
    if ((string)snippet["type"] != "upload") continue;

    var description = (JValue)snippet["description"];
    Console.WriteLine(description.Value);
}
```

Comment: deu erro em `var snipper = item["snippet"]; `Cannot applying with [] to an expression of type object`

Comment: coloca o código todo aqui

Comment: http://prntscr.com/91p33u

Comment: ah ta eu errei! coloquei foreach(object ...) é foreach(var ...)

Comment: olha a sua terceira linha, está com object... muda pra var :)

Comment: eu li tao rapido

Comment: isso aí! acontece! :)

Comment: valeu mesmo! pois como a Youtube Api v2 acabou para a plataforma .NET ai eu fiquei \0/ desesperado por um método de resolver o problema. : )

Comment: é e no caso de o `type` não for igual à `upload`?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/91p6t3

Comment: vc quer fazer o q? filtrar os itens onde o type seja igual a upload somente?

Comment: bem sim,.......

Comment: editei a resposta, é a forma mais simples... você poderia usar LINQ também, mas acho desnecessário, mas caso queira ler a respeito, aqui vai http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: Ok irei tentar isto!

Comment: Pivoan! Podes me ajudar a ler agora este json?

http://powdertoy.co.uk/Browse/Comments.json?ID=1681176&Start=0&Count=20

é um sistema de comentário gerado de um simulador, mas quero coloca-lo em xml e não consigo!

Comment: ta aí! http://s13.postimg.org/oo4rvhrfb/Capture.png